# Is there any Virtual Constructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

is there any term call Virtual Constructor in Java?then where we need to use this?

Comment: also asked and answered here http://www.coderanch.com/t/532258/java/java/there-any-Virtual-Constructor-Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "virtual constructor." Constructors are called recursively up the class hierarchy. Every constructor must call its super-class constructor as the first thing. (The call can be omitted if it is to the no-arg constructor, in which case the compiler will automatically insert it.)

As an aside, Java doesn't have virtual methods. Or, more precisely, every instance method is virtual (in the C++ sense).

Comment: does not answer the question. Should be a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @GeorgeXavier - In what way does it not answer the question? (Well, in the narrowest sense, it doesn't. I could have added the word "No.") It describes how constructors work in Java (as opposed to languages that have virtual constructors) and OP thought that was good enough to give it a check mark.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but OP did not appear to be asking how constructors in general work, rather what a virtual one is, (if not there, why), and what it is used for. Virtual constructors do exist and thus, the definition would be applicable to the answer. Additionally, why it does not work could be of course explained by the object construction internals, as you have successfully provided. Lastly, what it is used for is not answered, depending on the definition, given that that the question is asked, like almost any programming pattern, has a use.

Answer (score 5):

Virtual Constructors are not a part of the Java language, but the term might be applied to some design patterns

For example, calling `object.clone()` on an object that supports it will produce a new object (much like `new ClassName(object)` if you have a copy constructor) and thus resembles a constructor, but is polymorphic.  In "Effective Java" Joshua Bloch advocates the use of Static Factory methods as another way of achieving polymorphic object creation in certain circumstances.

For the use of the term in the C++ context look at: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by virtual constructors? If it is like virtual function in C++ there is no virtual constructor in java.

Comment: He means a factory method that constructs the object and returns it. The actual constructor is left private. Additional methods might be required on the object after construction and since it is bad practice to call methods on self inside constructor for the object is not fully constructed and can produce unintended results especially in multithreading, one would make the constructor private forcing the user to construct it via a method instead. That method includes the required methods on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware off. "[Default Constructor](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html) " yes. Delphi has virtual constructors, most other languages does not. See the Factory pattern for something related.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the definition of virtual constructor. If by virtual constructor, you mean static method that calls a private constructor as part of some factory patterns, then yes there are virtual constructors. I have found them very useful at times, when methods must be called on self after construction. All you have to do is simply set the constructor to private, and within the class, include a static method that creates the class object instance and returns it. This is useful when methods need to be called on the object before the user is able to use it. Since it is a very bad idea to refer to self in the constructor due to the fact that the object is not fully constructed, one can use a virtual constructor to call the methods after instantiation and before the user may have access to it.